# How to build my own env for DRL training using Ray RLlib

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am building my own env for DRL training using Ray RLlib. I am not allowed to used Gym or any other existing environment.

I started with importing ray in Google Colab. But I am getting error of - **No module named 'ray.rllib.agents'**

```
!pip install "ray[rllib]" tensorflow torch
!pip install ray[tune]
```

```
import ray
from ray import tune
from ray.rllib.agents import PPO  # Use the DRL algorithm that fits your scenario
from ray.tune.logger import pretty_print
```